# Issue when migrating from SQLite to PostgreSQL in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I'm trying to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL. "makemigrations" works fine, but when I run the "migrate" command, everything gets complicated.

Hello, I'm new to using Django, and I'm encountering the following error when trying to migrate from SQLite to PostgreSQL with an new database

[image: image 1]

When I started the development of the project, I used fields like TimeField in my model. I'm attaching a snippet from my 0001_initial.py.
[image: image 2]

Later, I realized that I should use time values differently and decided to modify the model to make them of type FloatField. Snippet from my migrations file 0004_alter_test_time_human_and_more.py
[image: image 3]

I believe I understand that the issue is when I run the 'migrate' command, Django goes through all migration files, and that's where the conflict with PostgreSQL arises. Has anyone faced the same issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) DO NOT use SQLite as test platform for what will be a Postgres backed app. I love SQLite but it is too different from Postgres  to serve as a stand in. 2) You got bit by 1) because SQLite basically ignores the defined data type of a column and will allow you to shove anything into a given column. Postgres is a lot stricter about types. 3) The specific problem is SQLite allowed you to use a `float` value in a `time` column and Postgres does not allow that.

Comment: Can I simply delete the SQLite file, the migrate folder, and pycache from all my apps, and then rerun 'makemigrations' and 'migrate' with my PostgreSQL database configured in settings.py?

Comment: I have no idea as I don't use migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way to solve this issue, generate all migrations again. follow the steps.

1. Update your DB Connection to PostgreSQL (Delete tables if any already created in PostgreSQL)
2. Delete all migration folder and files inside migration folders in all your django apps, you created.
3. Generate migration again for all your apps with command. You must mention your app name in make migration command.

   python manage.py makemigrations your_app1 your_app2 etc...
4. run migrate command

   python manage.py migrate